# How I can multiselect in highmap?

Tags: javascript, highmaps

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtScA.png)

How I can select multiple areas by pressing "ctrl"+mouseclick?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable point selection, and multiple point selection by setting [`allowPointSelect: true`](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series%3Cheatmap%3E.allowPointSelect) on a given series. Not all series types support this, but several of Highmaps series types do.

For example see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s938zLr3/) demonstration where you can:

- Left click to select single points
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left click to select multiple points

You can then for example get the selected points using [`Chart.getSelectedPoints()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/Chart.getSelectedPoints).